# `cat <does_not_exist | perl` succeeds

Tags: bash

I have a makefile which succeeds where it should fail because a line like this

```
 ./preprocess.sh <PARTIAL_SOURCE | perl >FINAL_SOURCE
```

succeeds even though `PARTIAL_SOURCE` doesn't exist yet.

This isn't a quirk of `preprocess.sh`, it seems to be something to do with bash/sh

```
$> cat <does_not_exist && echo ok || echo no
bash: does_not_exist: No such file or directory
no
$> cat <does_not_exist | perl && echo ok || echo no
bash: does_not_exist: No such file or directory
ok
```

Why does the first fail but the second succeed?

Comment: What is your requirement? and what do you intend to achieve?

Comment: The requirement is for `FINAL_SOURCE` to be written if and only if the full chain of commands which generates it succeeds.

Comment: Your requirement is quite vague actually. The `preprocess.sh` reads from `PARTIAL_SOURCE `  and you pipe a `perl` command's output to `FINAL_SOURCE` ( not sure a file or variable) only if the previous command succeeds?

Answer (score 2):

The second succeeds because `perl` succeeds. The exit code of a pipeline is the exit code of the last command in the pipeline. In this example it's `perl`. It receives empty input, does nothing with it, so it exits with 0, as it should.

As another example, this is successful too:

```
$ a | b | perl && echo ok || echo no
-bash: a: command not found
-bash: b: command not found
ok
```

If you don't want `perl` to get executed before `PARTIAL_SOURCE` is ready,
you need to test for it before the pipeline:

```
if [ ! -f "$input" ]; then
    ./preprocess.sh < "$input" | perl >FINAL_SOURCE
fi
```

Or wait for the input to be ready:

```
while [ ! -f "$input" ]; do sleep 1; done
```

Comment: Obvious follow-up, how can I make it fail?